# When using an Angular route Guard: 'Observable<true | undefined>' is not assignable to type > 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, angular-guards

I'm new to Angular.

How can I solve this problem?

I have installed Angular `CLI: 11.0.7` and Node: `12.18.4`

I have installed an Angular route guard:

```
ng g guard auth --skip-tests
```

**The error:**

> Error: src/app/_guards/auth.guard.ts:15:5 - error TS2322: Type
> 'Observable<true | undefined>' is not assignable to type
> 'Observable'.
> Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
>
> ```
>  15     return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
>         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>  16       map(user => {
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ...
>  19       })
>     ~~~~~~~~
>  20     )
>     ~~~~~
> src/app/_guards/auth.guard.ts:16:11 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.
>
> 16       map(user => {
>              ~~~~~~~~~
> ```

[image: guard]

**The Codes:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AccountService } from '../_services/account.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) return true; // the problem occurs here!
        this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!')
      })
    )
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly because nothing is returned from the `map` operator when `user` is undefined. Try to return something

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) return true;
        this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!');
        return false;
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Or better yet, you could use `tap` operator instead of `map` to perform side-effects like the 'toastr' notification.

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toastr: ToastrService) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (!user) this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!')
      })
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked for me. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a double-not operator to return the value. It's important to emit a value in both cases with a definitive value, either true or false.

```
      map(user => {
        if (!user) {
          this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!')
        }
        return !!user;
      })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. That because Typescript enforced some typing in newest version. When you get :

*Error: src/app/_guards/auth.guard.ts:15:5 - error TS2322: Type 'Observable<true | undefined>*

It means you try to return NOT BOOLEAN - in that case *undefined* - from guard which has specific list of types it can return. That is :  *Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree*. As you can see ther is no UNDEFINED at all.
You did not specified *return* for all 'branches'. That is in your case.  Simply saying return true or false real clear.

```
  map(user => {
    if (user) return true; // HERE YOU RETURNED TRUE 
    this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!')
    // HERE YOU DID NOT RETURNED return false;
    // from where interpreter should know what should be return 
    // when user is FALSE? ... it is not specified. Isn't it ?
  })
```

There is also one more issue in that training on Udemy. When you define your *this.accountService.currentUser$* it may be *undefined* case. Newest Typescript do not like unclear types - what is actually good thing.

In my case I put wrong types on this.accountService.currentUser$ to User | null.

```
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User | null>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();
```

Null did that I received USER or NULL which in condition !null caused it did not enter condition. Exactly same situation would be with *undefined*. My solution was following:

```
       canActivate(): Observable<boolean>  {
        return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
          tap(user => { 
            if (user === null) this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!');
   // your case should be:
  // if (user === undefined) this.toastr.error('You shall not pass!');
          }),
          map((user: any) => {
           return user ? true : false;
          })
    
        );

  }
```